# Does Postgresql create a new tuple for an no-change update statement?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I need to fix some data issues in a Postgresql database, the primary of which is trimming whitespace from text columns. I'm doing this using a statement like:

```sql
UPDATE app.products
SET "description" = TRIM(BOTH FROM "description")
```

Issuing this on a test database returns `UPDATE 2000`. The test table contains 2000 rows of which only 1 actually would change with whitespace trimming. Is this resulting in Postgres creating new, unnecessary tuples? Would there be a benefit to adding a WHERE clause? Most of the target columns aren't indexed.

```sql
UPDATE app.products
SET "description" = TRIM(BOTH FROM "description")
WHERE "description" LIKE ' %' OR "description" LIKE '% '
```

Comment: If you are using WHERE why not use the same expression: `SET "description" = TRIM(BOTH FROM "description")
WHERE "description" != TRIM(BOTH FROM "description")` ? The LIKE expressions you show may not filter the same rows.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ seems like a good improvement to the where case if the answer ends up being that the where is helpful. Cheers

Comment: The `where` clause has two effects: 1) it affects which rows are updated 2) it potentially allows Postgres to use an index to faster find the rows needing updating.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this will modify all rows, even if the value doesn't change.

If you want to avoid that, either use a `WHERE` condition:

```
UPDATE app.products
SET "description" = TRIM(BOTH FROM "description")
WHERE "description" IS DISTINCT FROM TRIM(BOTH FROM "description");
```

or use the [`suppress_redundant_updates_trigger()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-trigger.html#BUILTIN-TRIGGERS-TABLE) trigger function to define a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger on the table.

Avoiding the unnecessary updates will improve the performance and reduce table bloat.

Comment: Is better to use IS DISTINCT FROM in the case when it might be NULL

Comment: @RomanTkachuk How true. I have fixed the answer.